# Computing avg test scores using a while loop

Tags: c++

Ok so, I am trying to write a program using a 'while' loop to compute the the average of a certain # of test scores. My 1st input is the amount of tests, and every input afterwards is a set of scores (so say 1st input is 5, then the next 5 inputs are 5 different test scores). I have to input all the variables at once in order to find the sum of all the test scores and then the computed average.

I am completely stuck on how to do this and don't even know where to start.

Answer (score 1):

Some pseudocode

```
total <- 0
N <- input number of tests
i <- 1
while i <= N
    data[i] <- input data
    total <- total + data[i]
    i <- i + 1
avg <- total / N
```

Answer (score 0):

To get you started but not give too much away...

To do this the way I think you want to do this:

First take input for the # of tests.

```
Cin >> test_amt;
```

Okay, so now you know how many tests there are. Great! So now you should use a while loop to go through each test and take in input for the score! I would use a for loop here, but if you want to use a while loop, then sure.

```
counter = 0;
while(counter != test_amt-1)
{
     cin >> score;
     //I would use a vector to store each score. 
     //this way, you easily know which score matches up with which test 
     score = 0;
     counter++;
}
```

I hope this can get you started. If not, just let me know and I would be glad to help more.

Answer (score 0):

You can store scores in a [std::vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) and calculate the sum with [std::accumulate](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/numeric/accumulate/).

Answer (score 0):

Take all the scores in a single variable by adding them one after other and finally get the average. Below I have given a hint that will help you to use `while` loop. But you can use your own logic for it:

```
int test_amount, counter = 0, total = 0, score;
int avg;

cout<<"Enter test amount"<<endl;
cin>>test_amount;
while(counter < (test_amount-1))
{
    cout<<"Enter the test score"<<endl;
    cin>>score;
    total=total+score;
    counter++;
}
avg = total/test_amount;
```

If you wish to store the scores as well you may think of vector or array. As the number of 'test amount' is not fixed, you can also go for dynamic array, linked list etc. Think about other approaches, post your own code and Google is also there with all kind of help.